# How to get UIImage from JSON Data response?

Tags: ios, json, swift, uiimage

I trying to get image in bytes and create `UIImage` from it, but I can't understand how can I parse it.

My code:

```
func getAvatar() {
    NetworkManager.shared.getAvatar(methodPath: "www.xxxxxx.xxx", params: nil) { (data) in
        guard let dataValue = data as? Data else {return}
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            do {
                let response = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dataValue, options: .mutableContainers)
                print(response)
            } catch {
                print("Class - HomePageHelper, Method - getAvatar = \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In postman, I get something like this:

[image]

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This response is formatted as `Data`.

You can simply create instance from `UIImage` using it, after your optional

chaining `guard let dataValue = data as? Data else {return}`

Use this `dataValue` to make a `UIImage` like this.

```
let img = UIImage(data: dataValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to provide detailed solution.

I have used this method for download data objects from the internet.

```
    public func getData(from url: URL, completion: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> ()) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: completion).resume()
    }
```

And here implementation of this code for download an image from the internet.

```
        if let urlPath = model?.iconUrl, let url = URL(string: urlPath) {
            NetworkClass.sharedInstance.getData(from: url) { (data, response, error) in
                guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
                DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                    self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage)

```
imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:urlStr), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
```